# crypto_server exception exit: {einval, [{erlang,open_port,[{spawn, "crypto_drv elibcrypto

Tags: erlang

I having crypto_server problems:

```
    =CRASH REPORT==== 23-Jul-2019::10:20:17 ===
      crasher:
        pid: <0.49.0>
        registered_name: crypto_server
        exception exit: {einval,
                            [{erlang,open_port,
                                 [{spawn,
                                      "crypto_drv elibcrypto 
    c:/myapp/lib/crypto-1.5.3/priv/lib/win32/elibcrypto"},
                              []]},
                         {crypto_server,open_ports,2},
                         {gen_server,init_it,6},
                         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
      in function  gen_server:init_it/6
    initial call: crypto_server:init/1
    ancestors: [crypto_sup,<0.47.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.48.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 610
    stack_size: 23
    reductions: 425
  neighbours:
```

and the application doesn't start:

```
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) 
({application_start_failure,crypto,{shutdown,{crypto_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Comment: I got installed OpenSSL-Win32 and erlang 5.6.5 (R12B-5) because is an old version application, that I have to fix and can't change erlang version because that version is installed on production. But my windows pc crushes and got a new one, and now the application do not start :(

Comment: Uninstall openssl version 1.1.1 and install Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1g and problem solved, ty

Answer (score 0):

`einval` is a is a linux error that means invalid argument. Erlang returns quite a few of those types of errors back to the user. If you need a handy lookup table, you check look [here](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html).

I'm guessing the version of OpenSSL you have installed is incompatible with the old version of erlang. You could always start a trace on the init and see what's happening in during all of the message passing. You'll have to add the trace to your start up code before starting up the crypto lib. Here's a basic primer on tracing.

You must start the tracer program:

```erlang
dbg:tracer().
```

Then you need to identify which process(es) you'd like to trace. The simple version is to watch all processes. (`c` is short for `[call]`, which means trace all function calls.)

```erlang
dbg:p(all, c).
```

Finally, say what function calls you're interested in tracing by Module; Module and Function; or Module, Function, and Arity. You can use `'_'` in place of any of them.

```erlang
dbg:tpl(Module, cx).
dbg:tpl(Module, Function, cx).
dbg:tpl(Module, Function, Arity, cx).
```

You can turn tracing off with a similar function that disables tracing for all functions; by Module; by Module and Function; or by Module, Function, and Arity. Again, you can use `'_'` in place of any of them.

```erlang
dbg:ctpl().
dbg:ctpl(Module).
dbg:ctpl(Module, Function).
dbg:ctpl(Module, Function, Arity).
```

A simple, working example that you can copy/paste into a fresh repl:

```erlang
dbg:tracer().
dbg:p(all, c).
dbg:tpl(file, open, cx).
file:open("idontexist", []).
dbg:ctpl(file).
file:open("idontexist", []).
```

That should produce something like:

```erlang
1> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.299.0>}
2> dbg:p(all, c).
{ok,[{matched,engine@ryan,215}]}
3> dbg:tpl(file, open, cx).
{ok,[{matched,node@sam,1},{saved,cx}]}
4> file:open("idontexist", []).
(<0.50.0>) call file:open("idontexist",[]) ({erl_eval,do_apply,6})
(<0.50.0>) returned from file:open/2 -> {error,enoent}
{error,enoent}
5> dbg:ctpl(file).
{ok,[{matched,node@sam,95}]}
6> file:open("idontexist", []).
{error,enoent}
7>
```